# Using sed command to replace one set of values from a specific line and specific position

Tags: bash, shell, sed, replace

I have a text file like

```
    -7.9     8.5    1235  125478.30   9632
    32656.12   0.0   0.0    2365.12      h
    254    3365    12543     kk       l423
```

My aim is to replace the position where 2365.12 occurs with another variable.
This will happen in a loop for more number of iterations.

Initially I used sed to replace quoting the value. But i had problems with the occurrences. The same value might be there in the same line before. But i want exactly this position of the value to be replaced.

Hence I used the following command, that will take the postions into count to replace.

```
   sed -i"3s/^\(.\{32\}\)\(.\{7\}\)\(.*\)/1$variable\3" outputdata.txt
```

Now my problem here is, when a value with lesser number of digits is replaced in one loop, the following values come near. And hence during the next loop, the position count messes up with the next value.

Hence it would be so great if anyone can help me out with a way in which 
either I can replace the set of positions that are only non space
or replace the following set of values or the remaining part of the line with a space preceded everytime it is replaced. or some other method wherein I can point to that value and replace it.

The number of spaces separating the values can be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `printf`, for example:

```
$ for x in 1 1000; do echo "foo [$(printf '%7s' $x)] bar"; done
foo [      1] bar
foo [   1000] bar
```

In your case it would mean replacing `$variable` with `$(printf '%7s' $variable)`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, what you are seeking is this :

```
 $ awk -v myvariable='XXXXX'  '{ if( $4 == "2365.12" ) { $4 = myvariable }; print $0}' input.txt
-7.9     8.5    1235  125478.30   9632
32656.12 0.0 0.0 XXXXX h
254    3365    12543     kk       l423
```

Please let me know if it helps.

Additionally, if you want this to happen in a specific line, you can use :

```
awk -v myvariable='XXXXX'  '{ if( $4 == "2365.12" && NR == 2 ) { $4 = myvariable }; print $0}' input.txt
```

where NR is the line number.

Comment: I haven't used awk till now for this purpose. I ll check it